# Umlaut URLs fail in Tomcat when accessed via isapi_redirect

Tags: url-encoding, tomcat

I have some PDF Documents in my Servlet that contain ä,ö,ü,ß, etc.
On accessing the documents like this `http://hostname:8080/ServletName/test_ä.txt` the tomcat initially responded with an 404.
After changing the tomcat server.xml from this

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
connectionTimeout="20000"
redirectPort="8443" tomcatAuthentication="false"/>
```

to this

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
connectionTimeout="20000"
redirectPort="8443" tomcatAuthentication="false" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

I was able to access the documents.

My Problem starts when I want to get the documents via IIS (isapi_redirect).
When I call `http://hostname/ServletName/test_ä.txt` the Tomcat allways returns 404.
(Documents without umlaut are served correctly)

The corresponding lines in the tomcat access log look like this:

```
IP... - - [date...] "GET /ServletName/test_%C3%A4.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 6
IP... - - [date...] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 21630
IP... - - [date...] "GET /ServletName/test_%C3%A4.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 1001
```

The first two lines result from accessing the documents directly (`http://hostname:8080/...`).
The last line results from accessing trough IIS and isapi_redirect.

I dont understand why the call from the isapi_redirect is treated diffenrently by tomcat despite beeing the exact same URL (from the tomcat point of view).

Comment: Dang good question! I think I would be sniffing packets to see what is different. I suspect that would give me a clue. This may not be possible for you if you are using a host. I use WireShark here and would put a PC in between my servers temporarily to sniff out the packets. Perhaps there is an answer you can put on your Tomcat side that can do some of the same thing. I have no ideas on this. Sorry. But perhaps this can point you in a good direction. Who knows?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

Someone at the tomcat mailing list pointed out that the "URIEncoding" had to be added to the AJP connector config.

So, besides the change in the `<Connector port="8080"` tag in the Tomcat Server.xml you have to change this line

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

to this:

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

Now it works.